# wp_list_categories - custom post types

Tags: wordpress, wp-list-categories

I want to display certain wordpress categories, but also from certain post type - video.
Thats code only returns categeries from default posts.

```
function my_vc_shortcode( $atts ) {
return '
    <ul class="categories">
         '.wp_list_categories( array(
            'orderby' => 'name',
            //'post_type' => 'video', 
            'include' => array(20216, 20375, 20216),
            'title_li' => '',
        ) ).'
    </ul>
    ';
}
add_shortcode( 'my_vc_php_output', 'my_vc_shortcode');
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add post_type to the query. `'post_type' => 'video'`

```
function my_vc_shortcode( $atts ) {
return '
    <ul class="categories">
         '.wp_list_categories( array(
            'post_type' => 'video',
            'orderby' => 'name',
            //'post_type' => 'video', 
            'include' => array(20216, 20375, 20216),
            'title_li' => '',
        ) ).'
    </ul>
    ';
}
add_shortcode( 'my_vc_php_output', 'my_vc_shortcode');
```

Comment: There is no `post_type` parameter. Check https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_categories/

Answer (score 2):

`wp_list_categories()` function does not have `post_type` parameter. Check the Codex https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_categories/.

Also, a taxonomy in WordPress can be associated with a **more than one** post type. And a post type might have **more than one** taxonomy type.

However, there is a `taxonomy` parameter you can use for `wp_list_categories()` function. Something like this:

```
wp_list_categories( array(
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'taxonomy' => 'video_category' // taxonomy name
) )
```

If you use this code on different archive pages, then we can add another function to change taxonomy name depending on current loop's post type. Insert this in your **functions.php**:

```
function get_post_type_taxonomy_name(){
    if( get_post_type() == 'some_post_type' ){ // post type name
        return 'some_post_type_category'; // taxonomy name
    } elseif( get_post_type() == 'some_another_post_type' ){ // post type name
        return 'some_another_post_type_category'; // taxonomy name
    } else {
        return 'category'; // default taxonomy
    }
}
```

And this in your template file:

```
<?php echo wp_list_categories( [
    'taxonomy'  => get_post_type_taxonomy_name(),
    'orderby' => 'name'
] ); ?>
```